# How to get average for last N rows with specific formula

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to calculate an average and this is my current formula

```
=iferror(iferror(AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(B$2:B2156,B2157,D$2:D2156),AVERAGEIF(C$2:C2156,B2157,E$2:E2156)),AVERAGEIF(C$2:C2156,B2157,E$2:E2156)),AVERAGEIF(B$2:B2156,B2157,D$2:D2156))
```

This will calculate average between all cells up to 2156 but I would like to give me average only for last 10 hits. I tried with adding offset but I'm not sure where exactly to put it

Here is an example of my sheet
[image]

So I would like to get always the average of last 10 games for a home team.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I edited my original post with a screenshot of my sheet

Comment: I can’t really work with a screenshot... can you make a copy of your actual sheet and share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `indirect & max` method to average `Last N row` to solve your proble:

```
=average(INDIRECT("C"&max(0,count(C:C)-9)&":C"&max(0,count(C:C))))
```

Result:

[image]